# c# get value subset from dictionary by keylist

Tags: c#, dictionary

Ok, so you can get a single value by `dictionary[key]` or all values by `dictionary.Values`.

What I am looking for is a way to get all values for a given key set like so:

```
List<string> keys;
Dictionary<string, object> dictionary;

List<object> valuesForKeys = GetValuesFromDictionaryUsingKeys(dictionary, keys);
```

with

```
private List<object> GetValuesFromDictionaryUsingKeys(Dictionary<string, object> dictionary, List<string> keys)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Of course I could iterate manually over the keylist and use `dictionary[key]` each time and add all the values back to a list again, but I would like to use some more elegant way (e.g. Linq).

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try `keys.Where(k => dictionary.ContainsKey(k)).Select(k => dictionary[k])`.

Answer (score 8):

Why write function when you can have generic extension method for everyday use?

```
public static IEnumerable<V> GetValues<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> dict, IEnumerable<K> keys)
{
    return keys.Select((x) => dict[x]);
}
```

EDIT:
Than you can write:

```
var  valuesForKeys = dictionary.GetValues(keys).ToList();
```

Comment: Also you can use ContainsKey() like Rawling did if you are not sure that keys exist.

Comment: Nice. Wasn't aware of generic extension methods. Thanks!

Comment: Nice, +1. Remove the `ToList()` and just make it return the `IEnumerable<V>` and this would be even nicer and LINQy.

Comment: Yap, I returned List because this was required return type, but this is nicer way.

Comment: I just want to point out that if you don't want the subset to be duplicate, remember to run a `.Distinct()` on the `keys` first.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
    List<object> valuesForKeys = keys.Intersect( dictionary.Keys )
                                     .Select( k => dictionary[k] )
                                     .ToList();
```

or as requested:

```
private List<object> GetValuesFromDictionaryUsingKeys( Dictionary<string, object> dictionary, List<string> keys )
{
    // My code here
    return keys.Intersect( dictionary.Keys )
               .Select( k => dictionary[k] )
               .ToList();     
}
```

Use **.Intersect** to remove keys not present in the dictionary, it´s faster than a `.Where(k => dictionary.ContainsKey(k))`.

Remove the .Intersect instruction to allow **raising an exception** for a key not found in the dictionary.

Comment: As I understand, Intersect uses the default equality comparer, which may not be what you want to happen.  For instance if you initialize your dictionary as follows: new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase), this would not respect the comparer.

Answer (score 2):

```
private List<object> GetValuesFromDictionaryUsingKeys(Dictionary<string, object> dictionary, List<string> keys)
{
    List<object> nList = new List<object>();

    foreach (string sKey in keys)
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(sKey))
            nList.Add(dictionary[sKey]);

    return nList;         
}
```

Comment: Note that, lack of Linq goodness aside, this is stepping through a dictionary and searching a list - you'd be _much_ better off performance-wise stepping through the list and searching the dictionary.

Comment: If you gotta iterate, it'd be best to iterate the list of keys rather than the dictionary. It neutralizes any advantages the dictionary has in quick retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

Rawling answer works flawlessly, but if you know beforehand the keys exist on the dictionary, this may be more clear and efficient:
`keys.Select(k => dictionary[k])`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an extension method that is high-performance (compared against the other answers on this post) and optionally lazy, I suggest these:

```
public static IEnumerable<V> ValuesFromIntersectedKeys<K, V>(this Dictionary<K, V> dic, IEnumerable<K> keys)
{
    V value;
    foreach (K k in keys)
    {
        if (dic.TryGetValue(k, out value))
            yield return value;
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>> IntersectKeys<K, V>(this Dictionary<K, V> dic, IEnumerable<K> keys)
{
    V value;
    foreach (K k in keys)
    {
        if (dic.TryGetValue(k, out value))
            yield return new KeyValuePair<K, V>(k, value);
    }
}
```

Keys not in the dictionary are skipped over, and each lookup leverages the dictionary hash. Additionally, its lazy iterated. Simply call .ToList() or .ToArray() on the returned result if you want immediate evaluation.

Its also worth noting that KeyValuePair is a struct (value type) that will be created on the stack and remain there if evaluated on-the-fly, meaning the cost of new in this case is as cheap as any other struct value type. If you invoke .ToList() or .ToArray() or anything else that would result in heap allocations, you'll have to pay a steep cost but that's a given anyway.