# Array from Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary (key,value) like :

```
[A, green]
[B, blue]
[C, yellow]
[D, green]
[E, blue]
```

and also an array :

`[A,B,A,C,B,D,E]`

I would like to get this results: (from the dictionary return an array based on the previous one)

`[green,blue,green,yellow,blue,green,blue]`

Comment: `var result = array.Select(item => dictionary[item]).ToArray();`

Comment: How about `var result = array.Select(item => dict[item]).ToArray()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select multiple values from a Dictionary using Linq as simple as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544987/how-to-select-multiple-values-from-a-dictionary-using-linq-as-simple-as-possible)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464112/c-sharp-get-value-subset-from-dictionary-by-keylist ,

Answer (score 2):

You can either try *Linq*

```
using System.Linq;

...

var result = array
  .Select(item => dictionary[item])
  .ToArray();
```

Or good old `for` loop:

```
//TODO: put the right type instead of Color
Color[] result = new Color[array.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; ++i)
  result[i] = dictionary[array[i]];
```

Answer (score 1):

use Dictionary .Values

```
    using System.Linq;

    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "A" , "GREEN" },
        { "B" , "BLUE"}
    };

    string[] ary;
    ary = dic.Values.ToArray();
```

or just foreach dic.values , it almost same result with toArray() like this:

```
    foreach (string color in dic.Values)
    {
        //...
    }
```

Comment: This is not what he is asking for.

Comment: @Ignasi93 oh I didn't see clearly , my bad